# PresentedViewControllers memory leak

Tags: macos, swift, memory-leaks, xcode6, viewcontroller

I have a single window utility app for OS X written using storyboards in Swift, Xcode 6.  I have some helper windows which are presented modally with segues.  These are dismissed using dismissViewController(self).  However, the dismissed view controller is never deallocated due to the presentedViewControllers property of my root view controller, which maintains a reference.  In addition, each time a helper window is reopened, a new instance of the associated view controller is created rather than the previous instance, resulting in multiple instances and a memory leak.

How can a dismissed view controller be deallocated?

Comment: Why not try to keep re-using the same helper VC and just re-configure it with new contents using `prepareForSegue`? The concept of re-using a template occurs all over the place in iOS -- think dequeueReusableTableCell... You only need as many child VC instances as you have distinct templates.

Comment: The view controllers are initiated via storyboard segues, although one is initiated in code. I can get a previous VC instance from the presentedViewControllers property, but how can I set a segue to use a previous instance?  prepareForSegue passes a new instance as a parameter in the function call.

Comment: It seems this is a hole you've dug for yourself; your `presentedViewControllers` seems to be a custom property whose purpose is unclear to me -- unless it's a member of a poorly documented UIViewController subclass that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: presentedViewControllers is a property of the NSViewController class, and it is read only.  [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSViewController/presentedViewControllers)

Answer (score 2):

I also noticed that the `presentedViewControllers` property of my root ViewController was retaining multiple copies of its presented VC.

After some digging, I discovered I was calling `dismiss(self)` on the *presented* VC not on the *presenting* VC.

```swift
    // From inside the presented VC:

    // Does dismiss, but is still retained by the presenting VC:
    self.dismiss(self)

    // Does dismiss, and also does not retain:
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(self)
```

Weirdly both these do visually dismiss my presented VC, but only the latter actually removes it from the presenting VC's `presentedViewControllers` property.

Can anyone tell me why the former actually does visually dismiss the presented VC?

Answer (score 0):

A dismissed view controller can be deallocated by not holding any referenced to it anymore on dismissal. But you said that you *are* holding a reference. So if you are holding a reference in your root view controller then this is not going to happen. The question is: why are you holding a reference to it? Do you need to the model view controller again? If yes then everything is fine - you need it so it will stay.

Another usual reason that a view controller is not de-allocated is a delegate in it. In this case the delegate has to be marked as 'weak'.

Posting your source code would be helpful.

Comment: I am not holding a reference to it.  My root view controller is subclassed from NSViewController.  NSViewController has a read only property presentedViewControllers which is an array of the view controllers presented by it.  I can see all the instances of my presented view controllers in that array, but I can not set them to nil.  If I could reinitialize my root view controller, they should go away, but can I do that without relaunching the application?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the essentials of my view controller code:

```
class CoverIKImageViewController: NSViewController {

let zoomInFactor: CGFloat = 1.414214
let zoomOutFactor: CGFloat = 0.7071068

let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

var coverCGImage: CGImage!
weak var coverArtImageView: CoverImageView!
var imageProperties = [NSObject: AnyObject]()

@IBOutlet weak var toolControl: NSSegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var resolution: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var coverIKImageView: CoverIKImageView! {
    didSet {
        if coverIKImageView == nil { return }
        coverCGImage = coverArtImageView.image?.cgImage
        setIKImage(coverCGImage, url: coverArtImageView.imageURL)
        coverIKImageView.autoresizes = true
        coverIKImageView.delegate = self
    }
}

func setIKImage(cgImage: CGImage!, url: NSURL!) {
    if url == nil {
        imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage)
        imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage)
        coverIKImageView.setImage(cgImage, imageProperties: imageProperties)
    } else {
        coverIKImageView.setImageWithURL(url)
    }
    imageDidChange(coverIKImageView)
}

/* Additional functions here (not included) */

override func viewWillAppear() {
    self.view.window?.minSize = NSSize(width: 480, height: 560)
    setResolutionLabel()
    super.viewWillAppear()
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.view)
    coverIKImageView.undoManager?.levelsOfUndo = 8

    let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    center.addObserverForName(Notification.NewImageDraggedToIKImageView, object: nil, queue: queue) { notification in
        self.imageDidChange(self.coverIKImageView)
    }
    super.viewDidAppear()
}

override func viewWillDisappear() {
    IKImageEditPanel.sharedImageEditPanel().close()
    coverIKImageView.undoManager?.removeAllActions()
    super.viewWillDisappear()
}

override func viewDidDisappear() {
    super.viewDidDisappear()
    coverCGImage = nil
    coverIKImageView.delegate = nil
    center.removeObserver(self)
}
```

}

And here's how it is invoked in code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "Edit Cover Image":
            if let evc = segue.destinationController as? CoverIKImageViewController {
                evc.coverArtImageView = coverArtView
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSViewController property "presentedViewControllers" should not be the reason for the memory-leak, as it is just holding the reference as long as the (presented) view controller is presented.

What about this one?:

```
coverIKImageView.delegate = self
```

Is this delegate declared weak?

And how did you detect the memory leak? Please add this to check if the presented view controller is really not deallocated:

```
deinit {
    NSLog("CoverIKImageViewController deinit called")
}
```

Is deinit really not called?

Comment: Deinit is not called. I log it as you suggest. The memory leak is evident by opening and closing the coverIKImage multiple times. Memory usage steadily increases.  If I look at the presentedViewControllers property of my root view controller, there is a separate referenced instance of coverIKImageViewController for each time the segue was performed.

Comment: Can you post the project?

Comment: It could be checked with "Instruments", but I need to have the whole project.

Comment: It's too large to post. The leak is not detected by instruments, but I can see the memory usage go steadily up as I open and close the same helper window multiple times. I am going to see if there is a way I can reuse the same VC instance each time the segue is performed.

Answer (score 0):

I already asked you about this line:

```
coverIKImageView.delegate = self
```

What is with this delegate? How is it declared in CoverIKImageView? "weak"?

Instruments is not going to warn you about a "leak" in this case. You have to do further analysis. Short version: press Cmd+"I" in Xcode to start Instruments -> Choose "Allocations" -> Press the red button to Start Profiling -> Use your App and try to produce the memory leak -> Stop Instruments -> Set "Allocation Lifespan" to "Created & Persistent" -> Set the allocation type to "Allocations List" -> Type in your class name in the SearchBar "Instrument Detail" -> your class should be now in the list -> Press the small arrow button on the right of the memory address of your object ->

[image]

You should see now a list of Objects which are retaining and releasing your class instance. This will give you a hint about the leak.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the problem I see:

[Memory Leak with Bare Storyboard Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511635/memory-leak-with-bare-storyboard-project)

I did the same thing, created a barebones project like in this example.  The destination view controller is never deinitialized after closing the segued window, and a new destination view controller instance is created for each segue. References for each destination view controller instance are kept in the presentedViewControllers property of the root view controller.

The only workaround I see so far is to abandon using segues, and instead use the presentViewControllerAsSheet method with a single instance of the destination view controller saved as a property in my root view controller.  I have not found a way to initiate a segue with a specified destination view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code was creating a reference cycle:

```
    center.addObserverForName(Notification.NewImageDraggedToIKImageView, object: nil, queue: queue) { notification in
    self.imageDidChange(self.coverIKImageView)
}
```

However, that is only part of the answer.  Even without this line of code, the destination view controller would not deallocate after being dismissed.  This line of code is the culprit:

```
dismissViewController(self)
```

For reasons unknown to me, and only discovered through trial and error, replacing that line of code with this:

```
dismissController(self)
```

results in the view controller being deinitialized when dismissed.

Comment: In my case, calling `dismiss(sender)` caused the leak, calling `dismissViewController(self)` got rid of the leak.

Comment: Hmmm, I went back and checked this again. I still see the same behavior. If I use `dismissViewController(self)`, the view controller is never deinitialized, but if I use `dismiss(self)`, it is deinitialized.

Comment: Investigating further, the way I was using `dismissViewController(self)` was the problem.  If instead I use `presenting?.dismissViewController(self)`, the dismissed view controller is deinitialized.  Apparently this needs to be called from the presenting view controller to work properly.